# TinyXML: Save document to char * or string

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I'm attempting to use TinyXML to read and save from memory, instead of only reading and saving files to disk.

It seems that the documnent's parse function can load a char *. But then I need to save the document to a char * when I'm done with it. Does anyone know about this?

<strike>Edit: The printing & streaming functions aren't what I'm looking for. They output in a viewable format, I need the actual xml content.</strike>

Edit: Printing is cool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not familiar with TinyXML, but from the documentation it seems that by using operator << to a C++ stream (so you can use [C++ string streams](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/sstream/start)) or a [TiXMLPrinter class](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlPrinter.html) you can get an STL string without using a file. See [TinyXML documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html) (look for the "Printing" section)

Answer (score 22):

Here's some sample code I am using, adapted from the [TiXMLPrinter](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlPrinter.html) documentation:

```
TiXmlDocument doc;
// populate document here ...

TiXmlPrinter printer;
printer.SetIndent( "    " );

doc.Accept( &printer );
std::string xmltext = printer.CStr();
```

Answer (score 15):

**A simple and elegant solution in TinyXml for printing a TiXmlDocument to a std::string.**

I have made this little example

```
// Create a TiXmlDocument    
TiXmlDocument *pDoc =new TiXmlDocument("my_doc_name");

// Add some content to the document, you might fill in something else ;-)    
TiXmlComment*   comment = new TiXmlComment("hello world" );    
pDoc->LinkEndChild( comment );

// Declare a printer    
TiXmlPrinter printer;

// attach it to the document you want to convert in to a std::string 
pDoc->Accept(&printer);

// Create a std::string and copy your document data in to the string    
std::string str = printer.CStr();
```

Comment: If you're creating the character string for internal use, call printer.SetStreamPrinting() to omit indentation and line feed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite get what you are saying; your question is not clear.  I'm guessing you are wanting to load a file into memory so that you can pass it to the document parse function.  In that case, the following code should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The following code reads a file into memory and stores it in a buffer

```
FILE* fd = fopen("filename.xml", "rb"); // Read-only mode
int fsize = fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END); // Get file size
rewind(fd);
char* buffer = (char*)calloc(fsize + 1, sizeof(char));
fread(buffer, fsize, 1, fd);
fclose(fd);
```

The file is now in the variable "buffer" and can be passed to whatever function required you to provide a char* buffer of the file to it.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, edited.
I already am using the parse function, the problem is saving the document back to a char pointer after it has been loaded.