# load XML from variable, not File

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I'm trying to parse XML data stored in a variable, not a file. The reason for this is that program x replies to program y in XML, so it would seem to be best to directly parse the XML from the variable.

So far I have tried to do this in TinyXML, but I don't see an interface to load from a variable.

It's basically the opposite of [TinyXML: Save document to char * or string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110393/tinyxml-save-document-to-char-or-string), instead of saving to char, I want to load from char(or string)

For example instead of the following:

```
TiXmlDocument doc( "demo.xml" );
doc.LoadFile();
```

something like

```
doc.LoadVar(char*)
```

I also checked out RapidXML, but I also can't seem to find documentation to load from a variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the document in a string why not simply call the [`TiXmlDocument::Parse`](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#a14) method and be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TiXmlDocument::Parse`. See [tinyxml documentation](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#a14) for more details.